# CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE with IS TABLE OF

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

[image]

In this statement of create or replace type I am having an error in `is table of`. Here is the code:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TYPE Custos_SIN AS OBJECT 
(NUM_GRUPO VARCHAR2(30),CUSTO_TOTAL NUMBER, SINISTROS_TOTAL NUMBER);

CREATE or REPLACE TYPE custos_sin_table IS [here in red] TABLE OF Custos_SIN;
```

Do you know why?

Comment: The statements run, so the "error" highlighting must be a quirk of whatever environment you're using to run your code. What tool is it?

Comment: Does the syntax highlighting change if you terminate the statement with a `/` on a newline rather than a `;` on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember PL/SQL, it should be

```
CREATE or REPLACE TYPE custos_sin_table AS table of Custos_SIN;
```

not

```
CREATE or REPLACE TYPE custos_sin_table IS table of Custos_SIN;
```